# How to echo values from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I have 2 tables named `tbl_guard` and `tbl_records`. The `tbl_guard` has columns `guard_id` and `fullname`, while `tbl_records` has `guard_id` also. And here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_records";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "{$guard_id}";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

What I want to do is instead of the `guard_id` being echoed there in the loop, I want the `fullname` in the `tbl_guard` table.

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: use `$query = "SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fullname FROM tbl_records LEFT JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id = tbl_records.guard_id";` and  `echo "{$fullname}"`

Comment: You want to start reading the mysql documentation. it will help you explore and understand the sql language and what it offers. It also offers good examples.

Comment: @TamilSelvan I will try this and will tell you if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JOIN

```
$query = "SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_guard.fullname FROM tbl_records LEFT 
JOIN tbl_guard ON tbl_guard.guard_id = tbl_records.guard_id";
```

In PHP

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
.
.
.
 echo "{$fullname}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve seems to be a foreign key relation - you have to use JOINS. In your example:

```
SELECT r.*, g.fullname FROM tbl_records r LEFT JOIN tbl_guard g ON r.`guard_id`=g.`guard_id`
```

Read MySQL documentation, you will need this more often!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working already, here is my sql query:

```
SELECT tbl_records.*, tbl_residents.fname, tbl_residents.lname FROM tbl_records LEFT JOIN tbl_residents ON tbl_residents.stud_id = tbl_records.stud_id
```

Thanks everyone!